# How to get rid of console warnings for Atlaskit Editor?

Tags: reactjs, atlaskit

I am trying to use Atlaskit Editor in the React project. I have managed to add it using below code.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@atlaskit/editor-core';
import { WikiMarkupTransformer } from '@atlaskit/editor-wikimarkup-transformer';

const Text = () => {
    const [markupDocument, setMarkupDocument] = useState(false);

    const onChange = (editorView: EditorView) => {
        const transformer = new WikiMarkupTransformer();
        const wikimarkupString = transformer.encode(editorView.state.doc);
        setMarkupDocument(wikimarkupString)
    };
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Editor
                appearance="comment"
                allowStatus={true}
                placeholder="What do you want to say?"
                shouldFocus={true}
                allowTextColor={true}
                allowAnalyticsGASV3={true}
                allowLayouts={true}
                allowExtension={true}
                allowIndentation={true}
                allowRule={true}
                allowTables={{
                    allowColumnResizing: true,
                    allowMergeCells: true,
                    allowNumberColumn: true,
                    allowBackgroundColor: true,
                    allowHeaderRow: true,
                    allowHeaderColumn: true,
                    permittedLayouts: 'all',
                }}
                allowDate={true}
                onChange={onChange}
            />

            <span></span>
            <pre>{markupDocument}</pre>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Text;
```

But the problem is that I am getting a lot of warnings in the console log and unable to find any documentation or examples how to remove these warnings.

[image]

It would be a great help if someone can help with this.